# Closing view when canceled email

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I've been working on this app. I can't get the view of the email to close. What do I do?

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var Label: UITextField!

    @IBAction func SendOrder(_ sender: Any) {
        let recipients = ["EmailHere"]
        let title = "My order is:"
        let message = Label.text

        let mc: MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mc.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mc.setToRecipients(recipients)
        mc.setSubject(title)
        mc.setMessageBody(message!, isHTML: false)

        self.present(mc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I have tried the Delegate method but it comes up with this:
What do I do??

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqgTW.png

Comment: Your question is not clear, Please be specific what you need.

Comment: Did you implement the delegate method?

Comment: @rmaddy what is the delegate method, I've tried some but I none of them have worked.

Comment: Read the documentation for `MFMailComposeViewController` and `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` and search for the many examples for `MFMailComposeViewController`.

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya your delegate does not close it..

Comment: @Shadow_Programmer i use this delegates method in my project and working fine. did you show me your code that you impliment my method

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya I am just needing the email view to close when sent or cancel. I have tried your delegate again but it doesn't close it

Comment: @Shadow_Programmer is your mail successfully send ? from your email

Comment: @Shadow_Programmer put break point on func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) { } this method and check it your break point come  here or not

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya it sends fine but doenst close... i need it to close when canceled or sent..

Comment: controller.dismiss(animated: true) this line put in didfinishwith result method so your controller dismiss

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya break point works fine now but still doenst close.

Comment: @Shadow_Programmer please update your question with didFinishWith result() method

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya do you want me to replace `MFMailComposeResult` with `controller.dismiss(animated: true)`?

Comment: @Shadow_Programmer for sometime comment your this method and use mine one and check this in real device not a simulator .

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya i try everytime on a real device.. and you are say to put `controller.dismiss(animated: true)` but it tells me that it doenst work

Comment: @Shadow_Programmer i did not understand your problem because in my case my code solve my problem and also other one so .

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya my problem is that when i am sending the email, the email view will not close when i press sent or cancel..... and i have tried what you have said but they do not work.

Comment: @Shadow_Programmer did you upload screen shot that your mail windows open and then you send mail and window could not close.

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya with the 2nd answer, do i need to put anything before the `.sent` in the `case` section??

Comment: @Shadow_Programmer its big deal with to dismiss before with switch case or after but main part your controller not dismiss . so brother you upload a screen shot that mail window open and ya in result method create one alert that show mail send or cancel ok.

Answer (score 1):

**TRY THiS**

```
@IBAction func btnEmail(_ sender: AnyObject) {
       self.openEmail()

 }


func openEmail() {

    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mail.setSubject("Your subject Name")
        mail.setMessageBody("Contact Us", isHTML: false)
        mail.setToRecipients(["test@gmail.com"])
        present(mail, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
    }
    else {
        print("This device cannot send email")
    }
}


func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
    switch result {
    case .sent:
        print("You sent the email.")
        break

    case .saved:
        print("You saved a draft of this email")
        break

    case .cancelled:
        print("You cancelled sending this email.")
        break

    case .failed:
        print("Mail failed:  An error occurred when trying to compose this email")
        break
    }

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: { _ in })
}
```